# Grep: Copy a link with specific text

Tags: linux, bash, search, hyperlink, grep

I have a text file with many links which aren't in separate lines.

I want to save in another file probably, all the links which contains a specific word.
How can I do this with grep?

**EDIT**:

To become more specifique, I have a messy txt file with many links. I want to copy in onother file all links starting with https:://, ending with .jpg and contains anywhere "10x10" string for example

Comment: without knowing the format of your file, it is hard to give suggestion.

Comment: -1 since you don't give an example.

Comment: for example all the links starting with "https:://" and ending with ".jpg".

Comment: @user3202592: Please show exact sample of text with links. Could they be in <a href> tags, or are they always separated by whitespace before/after etc. Exact questions get the best answers.

Comment: sample of text file: <code src="https://scontent-a-mxp.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/p417x417/1525280_1383786471879370_34250220_n.jpg" data-non-starred-src="https://scontent-a-mxp.xx.fbbdn.net/hphotos-prn1/p206x206/1525280_1383786471879370_234f4250220_n.jpg" data-reorderid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the lines containing a specific word from the file like this:

`LINKS=$(cat myfile.txt | grep MYWORD)`

Then with LINKS, you can use a delimiter to create an array of links, which you can print to another file.

```
# Using a space as the delimeter
while IFS=' 'read -ra ind_link
do 
    echo $ind_link >> mynewfile.txt
done <<< "$LINKS"
```

Something along those lines I think is what you are looking for no?

Also if you need to refine your search, you can use the grep options such as -w to get more specific.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Don't use `cat file | grep foo`. Do `grep foo < file` http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Don.27t_Ever_Do_These

Answer (score 0):

Could you give us the specific word and an example of input file ?

You could try to use `egrep` or/and `sed` like this (for example) :

```
 egrep -o "href=\".*\.html\"" file|sed "s/\"\([^\"]*\)/\1/g"
```

Another exemple for all kind of http/https ressources links (whithout spaces in the URL) :

```
$ echo "<a href=http://titi/toto.jpg >"|egrep -o "https?:\/\/[^\ ]*"
http://titi/toto.jpg
$ echo "<a href=https://titi/toto.htm >"|egrep -o "https?:\/\/[^\ ]*"
https://titi/toto.htm
```

You have to customize the regexp according to your needs.

Comment: for example all the links starting with "https:://" and ending with ".jpg". this doen't return a result. can you explain me sed argument?